# ClickOnce downloading error

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, clickonce

I am using One-siemens software which has option to create ClickOnce application,

I have created the web app but I am facing an issue while downloading the application from the network (other IP range/Subnet)

I have attached the error file here,

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3130.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2053.0 built by: NET47REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/THCDC-GuardRM-3/Downloads/Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework%20(2).application
    Deployment Provider url     : https://XXX/click/Siemens.DesigoCC.ClickOnce/Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework.application
```

ERROR SUMMARY

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.

```
* Activation of C:\Users\THCDC-GuardRM-3\Downloads\Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework (2).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading https://XXX/click/Siemens.DesigoCC.ClickOnce/Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework.application did not succeed.
    + The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX'
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY

> No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS

> There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS

> - [6/22/2020 5:37:50 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\THCDC-GuardRM-3\Downloads\Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework (2).application has started.

ERROR DETAILS

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [6/22/2020 5:37:52 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading https://XXX/click/Siemens.DesigoCC.ClickOnce/Siemens.Gms.ApplicationFramework.application did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX'
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS

> No transaction information is available.

Comment: `The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX'` -> this looks like a DNS problem.

Comment: Basically I am not IT guy, so I have put DNS IPs as per given by the IT department.

Comment: and I can able to access Click once from the same network switch, also I want to add that I can ping the Server IP from anywhere in Network.

Comment: What did your IT department say about this?

Comment: they are not responding well, that's why I decided to find a solution by my self.

Comment: Its Solved by adding Host Name and IP to Hosts File